# C++ playing audio live from byte array

Tags: c++, arrays, audio

I am using C++ and have the sample rate, number of channels, and bit depth for my audio. I also have a char array containing the audio that I want to play. I am look for something along the lines of, sending a quarter of a second (or some other short amount of audio) to be played, then sending some more, etc. Is this possible, and if it is how would it be done.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this before with the library [OpenAL](https://www.openal.org/).

This would require a pretty involved answer and hopefully the OpenAL documentation can walk you through it all, but [here](https://github.com/EvolveLabs/node-mumble-audio/tree/master/src) is the source example which I wrote that plays audio streaming in from a mumble server in nodejs.

You may need to ask a more specific question to get a better answer as this is a fairly large topic. It may also help to list other technologies you may be using such as target operating system(s) and if you are using any libraries already. Many desktop and game engines already have api's for playing simple sounds and using OpenAL may be much more complex than you really need.

But, briefly, the steps of the solution are:

- Enumerate devices
- Capture a device
- Stream data to device

  - enqueue audio to buffer `alSourceQueueBuffers`
  - play queued buffer `alSourcePlay`

Comment: Do you happen to know of any good tutorials about getting and using OpenAL in this way.

Comment: I did provide a link which, though broken across a couple of files, isn't too complex. Here is an all in one I just found from searching: https://pastebin.com/rYp59nYg

Its a pretty low level api though, would be considered advanced. If you don't have much luck you may look into a game engine library like LibSDL, which isn't as low level but has some really easy apis for wav files and such.

http://wiki.libsdl.org/CategoryAudio